# Getting a chain code for an ed25519 expanded private key

Tags: rust, cryptography, bitcoin, elliptic-curve, ed25519

I am trying to generate an expanded private key for `ed25519_bip32::XPrv` class, but I'm having a problem understanding how to get a 32-byte chain code. I was able to generate a 32-byte secret key and then 64-byte extended secret key using `ed25519-dalek` crate from a mnemonic phrase (the short secret key is just an entropy and the extended key is the 64-byte hash of it with a modified bit). I also got a 64-byte seed from the same mnemonic, but I'm not sure how to go about getting a chain code from it.

[ed25519-bip32::Xprv](https://docs.rs/ed25519-bip32/0.4.0/ed25519_bip32/struct.XPrv.html) describes it as

> Effectively this is an ed25519 extended secret key (64 bytes) followed
> by a chain code (32 bytes).

Comment: bitcoin doesn't use ed25519. It uses ECDSA over k1. What's a chain code in this context?

Comment: @Woodstock I am trying to write a code for a Helium (HNT) HD wallet.